# UIScrollViewのスクロール量を指定する

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

`ScrollView`を指でスライドしたときにスライドする量を指定したいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
例えば`App Store`を開いたときに出てくる「ベスト新着App」のような行の`ScrollView`を作りたいと思うと、普通の`ScrollView`で作るのでしょうか？それとも`Paging Enable`を`YES`にした`ScrollView`で作るのでしょうか？
現在下記のサイトを参考に実装しているのですが、画面が横向きになった時にスクロールの量が変わって画像が中途半端に切れて表示されてしまいます。

http://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20120715

また、この「ベスト新着App」の`ScrollView`は1アイコンごとにスクロールできるようになっています。これを実現させるためにはスクロール量を指定しなければいけないと思うのですが、それとも何かスクロール量を指定する以外の方法でスクロールが行われているのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

対応OSがiOS6.0からなら`UICollectionView`が使えます。

`scrollToItemAtIndexPath`というメソッドを使うと表示位置を調整することが可能です。  
例えば`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`や`scrollViewDidEndDragging`等と組み合わせるとスクロールが止まった後に位置調整ができます。

[scrollToItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:)  
[UICollectionViewScrollPosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UICollectionViewScrollPosition)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    〜 中略 〜
    // 位置を調整
    [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPathindexPathForRow:row inSection:0]
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                    animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。UICollectionViewですか。こちらの方がページングのUIを実現できそうですね。ScrollViewではなくこっちで実装し直そうと思います。ありがとうございます。あと、scrollToItemAtIndexPathメソッドのNSIndexPathindexPathForRow:rowのrowには何を入れたらいいのでしょうか？イマイチ分からずに数字を入れてみると「'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path」とエラーが出ます。。。

Comment: @kojianu 数字で大丈夫です。表示対象の要素の範囲内で指定してください。`UITableView`の`cellForRowAtIndexPath`と考え方的には同じです。

Comment: 位置調節できました！ありがとうございます！